# call local python file from angularjs in atom

Tags: python, angularjs, atom-editor

I am experimenting on the atom text editor and i am facing this issue.

my code is as below:

this is the html angular file test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
        {{ x.name + ', ' + x.age }}
      </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('test.py').then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data;
    });
});
</script>
```

and the python file test.py is as below

```
import json

test = [{'name':'sample1','age':'24'},{'name':'sample2','age':'25'}]
print json.dumps(test);
```

when i open this browser in atom, i get the following error.

```
angular.js:10765 Failed to load file:///Users/harshajasti/Desktop/LibraryApplication/test.py: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

I get that i am getting the error because i am calling a local file, i dont know how to fix this though.

Comment: Note: this is not an atom issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a http server to serve the python file. The server should have CORS enabled. You can install a nodeJS based server from npm that has support for CORS or search for a python2 or python3 (depending on what you have) script that will launch the builtin simple http server with the CORS header.

CORS, put briefly, is a way of restricting how content can be requests between web servers. Without the CORS line in the header, browsers won't allow you to request the data from the other server. It has to do with the other server not having the header, not your own server.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for more information.

Just one possible solution assuming you have `npm` installed, you can find many many others through a search,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

```
npm i -g http-server    # This will install globally, -g flag
cd /Users/harshajasti/Desktop/LibraryApplication/
http-server --cors
```

This will print out what address its serving on then. The instead of reqesting `file:///Users...` request for example `localhost:8888/file.py`.

Comment: hey .. i did the mentioned. i still get the following error Failed to load localhost:8080/test.py: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: i got the connection running, but it throw a new error as below, this is supposed to be a simple problem. angular.js:12520 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=x%20in%20myData&p1=string%3Ao&p2=o

Comment: Serve the angular project from another server as well. You probably don't want to just load html files from your system when developing for various reasons. So have both servers running. You probably dont need to enable CORS in the angular project server, only the python file one. Or you can serve the python file from same directory as the angularjs project (say project/assets/file.py) and no have two servers and not CORS required.

Comment: I can't help you with angularjs issues. I only have some experience angular2, none with angularjs.